# Odoo - adding checkboxes to a listview

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to add a checkbox in each row of a listview.

I have my own model which inherits 'product.template', which means the listview is already
there for me to use. The problem is, it is possible to add a "checkbox" by inheriting from the
listview, and using 'position' to specify where I want my boolean to be inserted, but this boolean is
displayed as a checkbox which can not be checked or unchecked since the parent tree is not editable.

The whole point of this is to have a way to select products quickly in order to perform custom actions
faster.

Maybe my approach is mistaken.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What will these mysterious custom actions be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH.

Example:
This is the original Tree view of product.template

```
     <record id="product_template_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.product.tree</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Product">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="categ_id"/>
                <field name="type"/>
                <field name="state"/>
                <field name="uom_id" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
     </record>
```

Now I am going to add XPATH for adding checkbox(boolean) before name field. You can set your own position 'after/before' of any field

```
                 <record id="product_template_tree_view_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
                    <field name="name">product.template.product.tree.inherited</field>
                    <field name="model">product.template</field>
                    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_tree_view" />
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='name']" position="before>
                            <field name="boolean_field_name"/>
                        </xpath>
                    </field>
                 </record>
```

And don't forget to inherit the class in your python file, add the boolean field.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for editing the views. Depending on your preferences on your system.

### Keep original functionality:

- Create a new view for your model with the sequence higher than the original.
- Create a new action, set view_type to form (makes it editable) and point the tree view to your new view.
- Create a new menu for your new action

### Edit original functionality

- use xpath to add your fields into the view
- edit the original action

### **notes:**

**view_type parameter in action**

- tree = non editable
- form = editable